# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 for netCDF4

Tags: python, setup.py

on my Home Office I use Ubuntu 12.04. Now I try to configure python with netcdf4. I installed a lot of packages like numpy, pandas, matplotlib, hdf5, cython, h5py,... When I try to install netcdf4 I got the error message:

```
 Collecting netcdf
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages    /urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading netcdf-0.2.1.tar.gz (16.5MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.5MB 42kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy==1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from netcdf)
Collecting h5py==2.3.1 (from netcdf)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading h5py-2.3.1.tar.gz (1.1MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 223kB/s 
Collecting netCDF4==1.1.0 (from netcdf)
  Downloading netCDF4-1.1.0.tar.gz (562kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 563kB 340kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
checking /home/elly ...
checking /usr/local ...
HDF5 found in /usr/local

NETCDF4_DIR environment variable not set, checking standard locations..
checking /home/elly ...
checking /usr/local ...
checking /sw ...
checking /opt ...
checking /opt/local ...
checking /usr ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-q2Vs7i/netCDF4/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
    raise ValueError('did not find netCDF version 4 headers')
ValueError: did not find netCDF version 4 headers

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-q2Vs7i/netCDF4/
```

I searched different pages with similar issues and tried install-instructions:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-dev 
 sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
 sudo apt-get indtall python-all-dev
```

Do anyone have another idea to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same and I finally found the full list :

```
python3 -m pip install -U pip
pip3 install -upgrade setuptools
pip3 install netCDF4
```

it should work now :) it worked for me (`centos8`, `python3`)